# Need documentation of Progress application upgrade 11.3?

Tags: installation, openedge, progress-db

We are upgrading our Progress application on 9.1D to 11.3. Is there any sample document which we should look for our migration.

Currently we have built a new server where we are installing OpenEdge Enterprise RDBMS 11.3.

Can we backup the current database and dump it to new version.

Any suggestions/documents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Progress is very "kind" when upgrading but you have to take in mind that moving from 9.1d to 11.3 (11.4 is soon out by the way) is moving from 2002 to 2013. A lot has changed since then.

If you have program logic that relies on disc layout, os utilities (for example using UNIX, DOS or OS-COMMAND) they might be changed as well. So an upgrade might break even if the files compile without errors. You need to test everything!

You cannot directly backup and restore from 9.1D to 11.3, you need to dump & load.

What you need to do:

1. Back everything up! Don't miss this and make sure you save a copy of the backup. Back up database, scripts, program files (.p, .i, .r, .cls, etc). Everything! This is vital! Make sure you always have an untouched version left of the backup so you can restart if things go bad. Progress has built in utilities for backing up the database. OS utilities can also be used. **Be aware that OS utilities can not be used to create online backups. The backed up database will most likely be corrupt. Shut down the database before backing up when using OS utilities.**
2. Dump you current database. Data as well as schema. Don't forget to check for sequences etc.
3. Rebuild a new database on your new server with schema from old db. 
   If possible - move to Type 2 Storage Areas when doing an upgrade like this. It will increase perfomance. Check documentation and knowledgebase around required settings for this.
4. Load dumped data
5. Copy program files from old server to new
6. Recompile
7. Create startup scripts etc for starting databases as well as clients. Old parameters might not fit your new server, you most likely have more memory, faster CPU, larger discs etc.

All steps have several substeps. I suggest you dive into the documentation found at community.progress.com. You can also search the KnowledgeBase (knowledgebase.progress.com)

Also if you run into problems you can ask more specific questions here (but tag accordingly for example with [openedge](/questions/tagged/openedge)).

[11.3 Documentation](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1107.openedge-11-3-product-documentation.aspx)

[9.1D Documentation](https://community.progress.com/technicalusers/w/openedgegeneral/1324.progress-9-1d-and-webspeed-3-1d-product-documentation.aspx)

[KnowledgeBase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/)

Comment: Thsnks Jenscd. we have followed all the steps as you mentioned                    and we ahve successfully upgraded our system to 11.3 version.In order to validate the new systems what all the things we should check for? i have checked the following things 1. startup commands are working.

Comment: 2.db.st and db.pf files are same 3 .odbc driver files are installed.4.db tables and data are loaded.5. language and internation settings are checked in .ini file.6.PROMON utility is working.7.db block size 8192.Any other things i can look for validation?

Comment: Well. Test the application, does it perform as it should. Does GUIs look right, are batches running etc. Its impossible to say without a deeper understanding of your system... You should consider moving to Type 2 Storage Areas when doing an upgrade like this (check knowledgebase and documentation). Also your old startup parameters might not fit your new server. Most likely you have more memory, faster cpu, more cores, more disc etc. -B and -spin are primary parameters to look into.

Comment: Jenscd,i checked the application by generating a report.i see a field value for a field comes as 1'0024,00 instead of 1,0024.00.i checked the format its >,>>>,>>9.99.What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Most likely the default numeric format for the database/application. In your $DLC (Progress directory) you have a installd.ini that will tell you what your default numeric and decimal separators are. Look for numsep & numdec. Compare that to old installation. You can use startup parameters -numsep and -numdec to "force" a specific separator. You use ASCII values so you most likely want -numsep 44 and -numdec 46.